# date format function MMM YYYY in spark sql returning inaccurate values

Tags: pyspark, yearmonth

I'm trying to get month year out of a date but there's something wrong in the output only for the month year `December2020`, it's returning `December2021` instead of `December2020`, output

[image]

- in the `cancelation_year` column I got the year using this function :
  `year(last_order_date)` and it's returning the year correctly.
- in the `cancelation_month_year` I used
  `date_format(last_order_date,'MMMM YYYY')` and it's only returning wrong value for december 2020

Comment: Please update your question after reading : [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Avoid images, add proper code that we can just copy/paste to reproduce your case.

Comment: please write actual sample data instead of posting pictures

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [{"dt": "12/27/2020 5:11:53 AM"}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.withColumn("ts_new", date_format(to_date("dt", "M/d/y h:m:s 'AM'"), "MMMM yyyy")).show()

+--------------------+-------------+
|                  dt|       ts_new|
+--------------------+-------------+
|12/27/2020 5:11:5...|December 2020|
+--------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: still giving same result

Comment: I suspect your last_order_date is string so you have to convert to date first.